# Is Quitting The Answer?

Tags: work-environment

Recently I have taken a position in Finance that I did not have much experience in. I had informed the company that I did not have a background in finance other than some classes in college. They had assured me that it was okay because they would teach me everything I needed to know. After doing a project for them for the interview and their confidence in teaching me I took the position.

Knowing I did not have much experience I went into my first day ready to learn everything I possibly could. I had tried to be as proactive as I possibly could. I spent my time looking at videos that were suggested , asking for work , various projects and anything I could get my hands on. Without much guidance I began to notice how much coworkers would converse with one another . Being nervous about being qualified for the position I was timid. Soon after I have received insults, derogatory remarks and I have objects thrown at me daily. Trying to just fit in I thought I would outlast the hazing but after awhile it has not stopped. Constantly being asked if I'm applying for other jobs or if the hazing is too much.

While I tried to focus on work I had received little to no guidance, direction or even what to study up on or even talked about work on most days. Eventually I had been handed my own project that was shown to me once or twice which I feel is very intricate. Now that the project is mine I am completely responsible for it but I don't feel completely comfortable with it and I am expected to be. I don't feel comfortable asking questions as it seems to be frowned upon with noticeable distaste. Whenever a task comes across my desk I need to ask for help. I do not foresee a future in the position because I have absolutely no idea how to do the job. I can work with the projects that have been handed to me but I am expected to enhance them and I don't know how to approach that. I have informed my boss about this but I feel as though I'm still in a limbo where they don't know what to do with me.

So my question is should I try to "fake it until I make it" or is this a toxic work environment? I would feel down on myself to miss out on the great experience and pay.

Comment: having "have objects thrown at me daily" sounds pretty toxic to me.

Comment: What, exactly, is the "great experience" that you're gaining in an office where bullying is rife, you're not learning anything, and you have no managerial support?

Comment: Pro tip: "toxic environment" and "great experience" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think he means experience in the sense of learning new things.

Comment: Sounds like a stereotypical "banker bro" environment...

Comment: I think I saw this movie.

Comment: Are you the only one having objects trown at you ? Did you try to stand up to them ?

Comment: If you don't like working there, find another job and quit. Why do you need validation from random internet strangers?

Comment: Who hired you? Supposedly, that person is on your side. Also, it's unlikely that the hazing is a new thing in that office, and I bet that this person must be tired of hiring new people only for them to quit a couple of days/weeks later. Make an appointment with that person. Tell them your concern. Mention the hazing, the lack of support, and the inability to ask questions. If that person takes your concerns seriously, he'll get you the support/mentor you need, but if he doesn't, prepare to quit. that kind of environment can be super toxic (even if the rewards can be very high).

Answer (score 5):

Being insulted and having things at you are a clear sign of a toxic work environment. Unless you like to work with assholes (from this question, it seems you don't) or you want to receive training in how to become an asshole (I sure hope you don't) there is nothing for you there. You'll just be miserable until you leave.

Answer (score 0):

Some signs that everyone should know if they are thinking about quitting their present job as referred from business insider.

```
You're bored all the time.    
Your skills aren't being tapped.    
Your employer's goals and your personal mission don't match up.        
You've got the boss from hell.    
You feel like you can't ever win.    
You're not growing.    
You always watch what you say.    
Your company isn't invested in you.    
You worry about money — all the time.    
It looks like layoffs are coming.    
You can't picture yourself at your company in a year.    
You've got serious trust issues.    
You're burnt out.    
You dread Mondays.    
You can't laugh out loud at work.
```

Most of these signs are present there in your case so I would suggest leave to a better job where you can feel satisfied and see yourself happy.
For more detailed explanation visit [business insider](http://www.businessinsider.in/16-signs-its-time-to-quit-your-job/articleshow/51048837.cms)

Comment: Any reason for downvotes ?

Comment: I was not the downvoter but I guess it could be because you have clearly copied content from elsewhere without attribution.

Comment: "Elsewhere" being [Business Insider](http://uk.businessinsider.com/signs-you-should-quit-your-job-2016-2/) in this case...

Comment: I've referred to the link now